# Display image stored in SQLite3 via PHP Script

Tags: php, database, image

I have got an SQLite3 Database with several images in it. I want to display these Images in a Browser (Images are fetched from DB via PHP Script).

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$img=$this->getImgData($mid);
//next line is just for testing purposes
file_put_contents("/tmp/thumb.jpg", $img); 
echo $img;
exit();
```

The Problem is:
The Image /tmp/thumb.jpg can be viewed by any image Viewer, but the browser calling this php script (which gets the exact same data as in /tmp/thumb.jpg) refuses to display it.
How could that be?

Comment: No other headers/data/bytes at all have been sent prior to this code you're showing here, right? Sometimes a PHP warning/notice might slip through, too.

Comment: There is no output sent before that lines of code. If so, there would be a PHP Error message "Headers have already been sent". If i comment out the "header()" line there's only binary data in the browser - no human readable errors or warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Problem:
I copied the content type from a webpage to my IDE.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

It seems like the "space" between "Content-type:" and "image/jpeg" wasn't a space but rather any other invisible unicode char. So i just keyed in the header by hand - and it worked!

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Glad you found it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure not to have any characters written before this section

Most of the time there are spaces before a `<?php`, or in an include file somewhere above.

Doublecheck that!

Other than that everything look fine. IMO it should work.